# SQL error or missing database (near "," syntax error)

Tags: sqlite

I have this query with syntax error. Can you help me find the error please?
I spend couple of hour and I can't solve it. Thanks.

```
String sql = " INSERT  INTO appointments (patient_firstname, patient_surname, fees, time, date, doctor)"
                 + " SELECT (time, date, doctor)"
                 + " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE time = ?)";

pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,txt_firstname.getText());
pst.setString(2,txt_surname.getText());
pst.setString(3, txt_fee.getText());
pst.setString(4, (String) cbox_time.getSelectedItem());
pst.setString(5,txt_date.getText());
pst.setString(6, (String) cbox_doctors.getSelectedItem());
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Why do you have parenthesis around the column names in the select? The select also needs to return the same number of columns as you're trying to insert.

Comment: Plus your statement has one parameter but you're trying to bind 6?

Comment: Oh, and that select lacks a from! You should sit down with a good SQL tutorial and learn the basics of the language.

Comment: What I want to do is to insert those data but before inserted I want to check  time, date, doctor to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

The issues with your INSERT statement includes :-

- You appear to be attempting an INSERT SELECT where the VALUES to be inserted are obtained from the SELECT clause, but you are trying to mix this with VALUES. The two types cannot be combined.
- You are trying to select using columns within parenthesises and anyway those three columns WILL NOT match the 6 columns required for the insert.
- You only have 1 **`?`** to be bound, you are trying to bind 6.

I'd suggest that you could simplify matters by defining the table with a UNIQUE constraint on the doctor, date and time columns. Then use a standard **INSERT OR IGNORE** with the VALUES clause.

e.g. consider the following demonstration SQL :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS appointments;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appointments (patient_firstname TEXT, patient_surname TEXT, fees REAL, time TEXT, date TEXT, doctor INTEGER, UNIQUE (doctor, date, time));
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO appointments VALUES ('Fred','Bloggs',100.50,'10:00','2019-01-01',1);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO appointments VALUES ('Mary','Smith',100.50,'10:00','2019-01-01',2);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO appointments VALUES ('Sue','Bell',100.50,'10:00','2019-01-01',2);
SELECT * FROM appointments;
```

This results in :-

[image]

i.e Sue Bell's appointment has not been added because of the UNIQUE constraint conflict, which has been ignored so there is no error.

The log being :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS appointments
> OK
> Time: 0.177s

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appointments (patient_firstname TEXT, patient_surname TEXT, fees REAL, time TEXT, date TEXT, doctor INTEGER, UNIQUE (doctor, date, time))
> OK
> Time: 0.084s

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO appointments VALUES ('Fred','Bloggs',100.50,'10:00','2019-01-01',1)
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.083s

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO appointments VALUES ('Mary','Smith',100.50,'10:00','2019-01-01',2)
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.084s

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO appointments VALUES ('Sue','Bell',100.50,'10:00','2019-01-01',2)
> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0s

SELECT * FROM appointments
> OK
> Time: 0.003s
```

Comment: Thanks. I sorted out.

Comment: That's good. If the answer helped you out, then please tick it as the answer.